# Simple(r) ORM for PHP

Tags: php, orm

What is the **simplest** ORM implementation around for PHP? I'm looking for something **really simple and light** (in terms of LOC, since speed it's not crucial I don't need caches and what not), **preferably a single file or class package** that doesn't depends on XML or other configuration files and it's easy to deploy.

Reading other similar questions [Pork.dbObject](http://www.schizofreend.nl/pork.dbobject/) (which by the way is developed by one of SO users) was the closest I could find so far, and I'm interested in knowing if there are any other ORM implementations that might be **lighter than this one**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Doctrine and Propel are good, but can't say they are "simplest".
Here two alternatives - [PHP Active Record](http://www.phpactiverecord.org/) , [Outlet PHP ORM](http://www.outlet-orm.org/site/)

Hope one of them helps

Comment: Or try Idiorm - https://github.com/j4mie/idiorm

Answer (score 3):

I used ADODB Active Record: http://phplens.com/lens/adodb/docs-active-record.htm, it isn't too heavy.

Then again, if you want to make a light one, why not build your own?

Answer (score 3):

Why not try plain vanilla PDO (or mysqli if you work with MySQL and don't like PDO)? It's not exactly a full-blown ORM, but it allows fetching query results directly into an object. And it doesn't get any more simple, lightweight and zero-configuration than that. :)

Comment: I've been butting my head trying out 8.3 million different ORMs and this turned out to easily be the best solution for me. PDO are pretty straightforward, built-in and pretty nice. I hear mysqli is a bit slower but I haven't used it personally (for that reason). +1 for PDO, pretty much the lightest you can get.

Comment: @Garet Claborn - Actually [it's the other way round](http://jonathanrobson.me/2010/06/mysqli-vs-pdo-benchmarks), but even then the difference is negligible.

Comment: Oh nice, thanks for clearing that up ;p Good benchmark.

Answer (score 2):

For a lightweight solution, [phpDataMapper](http://phpdatamapper.com) might be a good choice.

Answer (score 1):

I've used [CoughPHP](http://www.coughphp.com/) in the past and been pretty happy with it's simplicity.

Comment: Not exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Ive just started to use Zend Framework and im pretty happy with it.

Comment: Still a lot bigger than Pork.dbObject.